# The proof of $\|T\|=\infty$ for $T: c_{00}\to c_{00}$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $T: c_{00}\to c_{00}$ given by
$$
T(\{x_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty})=\{k x_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}
$$

Here we use the $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ in in $c_{00}$

I try to show that $\|T\|=\infty$. I am not sure if my proof works.

we can choose $e_k=(0,\dots, 0, 1,0,\dots)$ for the $k-th$ coordinate is 1. Then $e_k\in c_{00}$ and $\|c_{00}\|_{\infty}=1$. Also, $T(\{e_k\})=\{ke_k\}$, then $\|T(\{e_k\})\|_{\infty}=k$. Hence, $\|T\|=\sup_{\|\{e_k\}\|=1} \|T(\{e_k\})\|=k$.

Comment: You are mixing sequences with entries of sequences. In your first sentence, $x_k$ is a number; so $Tx_k$ makes no sense.

Comment: You also have to specify the norm you are using on $c_{00}$.

Comment: No, as written it still doesn't make sense. If you are taking a supremum over $k$, the value cannot possibly depend on $k$. There's no fixed $k$ in your argument.

Comment: No, it's not. You need to choose (carefully) which sequence(s) you use. If you don't see it, try to write your quotient for a few concrete sequences (use sequences $x$ with $\|x\|=1$).

Comment: @MartinArgerami Ok, So we can choose $e_k=(0,\dots, 0, 1,0,\dots)$ for the $k-th$ coordinate is 1. Then $e_k\in c_{00}$ and $\|c_{00}\|_{\infty}=1$. Also, $T(\{e_k\})=\{ke_k\}$, then $\|T(\{e_k\})\|_{\infty}=k$. Hence, $\|T\|=\sup_{\|\{e_k\}\|=1} \|T(\{e_k\})\|=k$.

Comment: You are still mixing sequences and numbers, but that's the right idea. I'm leaving now, so I posted an answer to show how I would write it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After clarifying things in the comments, here's how the canonical way to prove this goes.

You let $e_k$, for each $k\in\mathbb N$, denote the sequence with $1$ in the $k^{\rm th}$ entry and $0$ elsewhere. When one notes that $c_{00}$ are the functions $g:\mathbb N\to\mathbb C$ of finite support, we have $e_k=\delta_k=1_{\{k\}}$, that is $e_k$ is the characteristic function of the set $\{k\}$.

Now you have $\|e_k\|=1$ and $Te_k=ke_k$, so
$$
\frac{\|Te_k\|}{\|e_k\|}=\frac k1=k.
$$
Then $\sup\{\|Tx\|:\ \|x\|=1\}\geq k$ for all $k$, which shows thath
$$
\sup\{\|Tx\|:\ \|x\|=1\}=\infty.
$$
As a final comment, it is uncommon (and weird to the trained eye) to say $\|T\|=\infty$. When the sup above is infinite, we rather say that the norm of $T$ doesn't exist.