# The norm of $T: c_{00}\to c_{00}$.

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the inverse map in [The proof of $\|T\|=\infty$ for $T: c_{00}\to c_{00}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4780504/the-proof-of-t-infty-for-t-c-00-to-c-00). That is the map $T:c_{00}\to c_{00}$ defined by $T(\{x_k\}_{k\ge 1})=\{x_k/k\}_{k=1}^\infty$. Here we take sup norm in $c_{00}$. I try to show the norm of this operator $T$ is bounded (or equal to 1?)

Take $x\in c_{00}$. Then
$$
\|T(\{x_k\}_{k\ge 1})\|_{\infty}=\sup_{k\ge 1}|x_k/k|\le \sup|x_k|=\|x\|_{\infty}
$$

So
$$
\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Tx\|=1
$$

Does it make sense to say $\|T\|=1$? Also, I am not sure why the author wrote $\|T\|\le 1$ but not $\|T\|=1$?

Comment: Where did you prove equality? You have only proved $\le$.

Comment: @geetha290krm But by the definition of the norm, $\|T\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Tx\|$. And $\sup \|Tx\|=1$, right?

Comment: Yes, but you have not shown that, your argument only gives you $\leq 1$. It is like saying $\sup_{n\geq 1} 1/(15782 n^5) \leq 10$, so the supremum is $10$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven So how to show that we can attain the equality? Also, one similar question as in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4783997/can-we-attain-the-norm-of-operator-t.

Comment: For a lower bound, we need to find a specific $x$ with $\Vert x \Vert =1$ and $\Vert Tx \Vert\geq 1$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Oh, I see. I can just take $x=(1,0,0,\dots)$, right?

Comment: Exactly, this yields the desired lower bound. Because, the supremum is bigger or equal than any particular choice of $x$ that we can make.