# Can we attain the norm of operator $T$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Following this question [The norm of $T: c_{00}\to c_{00}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4783990/the-norm-of-t-c-00-to-c-00?noredirect=1#comment10169205_4783990) about if we can attain the norm of operator $T$.

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ be a measure space. If we define $T: L_3\to L_1$ by $T(f)=hf$ for $h\in L_{3/2}$. I want to get the norm of $\|T\|$.

Apply Holder's inequality,
$$
\|Tf\|_1\le \|h\|_{3/2}\|f\|_3.
$$

Then
$$
\sup_{\|f\|_3=1}\|Tf\|_1\le\|h\|_{3/2}.
$$

So, we have
$$
\|T\|\le \|h\|_{3/2}.
$$

But how to say we can attain the supremum like $\|T\|=\|h\|_{3/2}$?

---

Update: I found this result:

> Let $1\le p<\infty$ and $1/p +1/q=1$. Then for every $f\in L_p$, we have
> $$
> \|f\|_p=\sup_{\|g\|_q\le 1}\|fg\|_1
> $$
> which the supremum is attained.

Hence, by this result,
$$
\sup_{\|f\|_3\le 1}\|Tf\|_1=\|h\|_{3/2}
$$
where the supremum is attained.

Hence,
$$
\|T\|=\|h\|_{3/2}
$$

Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result you quote is sufficient. For fixed $h\in L_{3/2}$ it holds that
$$ \sup _{\|f\| _3\leqslant 1} \|Tf\|_1 = \sup _{\|f\| _3\leqslant 1} \|hf\|_1 = \|h\|_{3/2}.  $$
Also for $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q} = \frac{1}{r}$ ($p,q,r\geqslant 1$), it holds that $u\in L_p$, $v\in L_q$ implies $uv\in L_r$, so $T$ is well defined.